# How create tree view in PHP?

Tags: php, treeview

I have array of users and every user can have parents:

```
array(6) {
    guest => NULL
    moderator => NULL
    member => array(1) [ //username
       0 => "guest" (5) //parent
    ]
    user => array(1) [
       0 => "member" (6)
    ]
    admin => array(1) [
       0 => "moderator" (9)
    ]
}
```

And I want to make tree view from this data. The result should look like this: http://www.phorum.org/phorum5/file.php/62/3237/treeview_lightweight_admin_screenshot.jpg

The result will be:

```
- guest
    - member
        - user

- moderator
    - admin
```

EDIT:

I tried to write tree generator, but i dont know how use recursion.

```
private function generateTree($node)
{
    $return = array();
    if(is_array($node))
    {
        foreach($node as $user => $parents)
        {
            if(is_null($parents))
            {
                $return[$user] = null;
            }
            if(is_array($parents))
            {
                foreach($parents as $parent)
                {
                    if(array_key_exists($parent, $return))
                    {
                        $return[$parent] = $user;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dump($user, $parent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

return:

```
array(2) {
    guest => "member" (6)
    moderator => "admin" (5)
}
```

left:

```
    user => array(1) [
        0 => "member" (6)
    ]
```

Comment: You pretty much already described what to do: print out that array recursevly and add css style to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can active this by making the HTML builder method [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). Essentially, the method invokes itself with an incrementing level variable (level 1, 2, 3, 4..) until the ultimate level has been reached. Every level contributes to the HTML code, depending on the level. A typical example would be:

```
function render($treeData, &$html, $level = 0) {
    foreach ($treeData->branches as $branch) {
        render($branch, $level + 1);
    }

    $html .= '<div class="section-level-'.$level.'">'.$treeData->currentLevelData.'</div>';
}

$html = '';
render($treeData, $html);
```

This is of course pseudo-code. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug you have some automatic views with `var_dump($array)` (for HTML render) or `print_r($array)` (plain text render). 
For a custom view you have to loop on your array and write your own HTML

Comment: I want to make custom view, but I dont know how make it if the depth of tree is more than one.